# Questions concerning the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This differential equation is a classic example of an ordinary differential equation which can be solved by separation of variables. My question concerns the validity of this method when one has to divide on both sides by y (which is a function of x) in order to separate the variables. To help the reader understand my question better, I write here, a typical solution to this problem as it often appears in different sources I have read.

Assume for now that $y\neq 0$

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=ky
$$

$$
\int{\frac{1}{y} dy} = \int{kdx}
$$

$$
\ln(|y|) = kx + C
$$

$$ 
|y| = e^{kx }e^c
$$

$$ 
y=Ae^{kx}\,\,\, A\neq 0
$$

Since $y=0$ is also a solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$ we have $y=Ae^{kx}$ is the general solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$

My questions:

When I read this I am assuming that $y \neq 0$ means that $y(x)$ is different from zero for all x in the domain of y. Otherwise you would have division by zero somewhere which is forbidden. The first chain of reasonings above then shows that if y is a everywhere non zero function that solves the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$ then this function must be able to be written in the form

$$ 
y=Ae^{kx}\,\,\, A\neq 0
$$

My concern is that after having mentioned the zero function $y=0$ as a solution that they then go on to conclude that all the solutions are of the form $y=Ae^{kx}$ where $A$ can now also be zero. I am not convinced by this.

I worry that there still could be some other function y out there which is zero for only some x in the domain of y that is also a solution!

This worry of mine seems to be glossed over in many other examples where differential equations are solved by separation of variables. Why can they be so sure that another solution doesn't exist?

Comment: Sorry for the errors in my code in the above question. This is my first time posting a question.

Comment: If $y=0$ that what is its derivative? I.e. what is the value of $y$ close to this point? Then go on from there

Comment: If $y_1$ is your other solution for which y(0) is also A, what differential equation is satisfied by $y - y_1$?

Answer (score 1):

The function $y$ is assumed differentiable everywhere so it must be continuous everywhere as well.

If $y$ is only zero part of the time then on its nonzero parts it has to take the exponential form that we have found, possibly with different constants $A$ on different disconnected components.

On the other hand, on the parts where $y$ vanishes so does its derivative by virtue of the original equation.

This gives a contradiction at boundary points of the zero set of $y.$